# How to setup proxy server which forward video data

Tags: c#, video, server, proxy

My problem:
I have web server A with link : http://mywebsitea.com/1.mp4?xxx=x1&x2.... (I called link A)
Now i would like to setup web server B with link : http://def1.com/secret.mp4?x=1&y2 (I called link B)
When visitor accesses link B,it will forward link A . Mean that in server B, we do not have any files (secret.mp4 is just virtual path , look proxy server ..but im not sure it is correct)
How can i do that ? or give me keyword to find solution in internet ?
Thank you so much !

Comment: Can you please specify what you tried.

Comment: Mean that i would like to hide sensitive url path ! Have you any ideas ?